# PowerShell to Search Hash Table Values with -notlike or -notmatch

Tags: powershell, hash, match

I'm attempting to search a hash table for keys that have values that are `-notlike` or `-notmatch` '*Snagit*'. I am able find an exact match with `-notcontains`.

**Data Example:**

```
Name    Value
Host1   FireFox,Snagit 7,Chrome
Host2   Internet,Chrome
Host3   Snagit 5,Internet,Stuff
```

**Code Example:**

```
$global:Csv = Import-Csv -LiteralPath $global:ConvertedSNWReport

$global:hash = @{}
Import-Csv -LiteralPath $global:ConvertedSNWReport | ForEach-Object {
    $global:hash[$_.'Computer name'] += @($_.Application)
}

$global:Results = $hash.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object {
    $_.Value -notmatch '*Snagit*' 
}
```

Comment: So, in the example you'd want to grab only the `Host2` entry, is that correctly understood?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Note that `*Snagit*` is not a valid regular expression (`-match`, `-notmatch`). It's a pattern for wildcard matches (`-like`, `-notlike`). For a regular expression you don't need to match leading or trailing text, since they aren't anchored by default (you need `^` and/or `$` for anchoring them), whereas wildcard patterns are by default anchored at beginning and end of a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest your `Where-Object` statements to accomplish this:

```
$results = $hash.GetEnumerator() |Where-Object {
    -not($_.Value |Where-Object {$_ -like '*snagit*'})
}
```

If any of the items in the individual value array matches `snagit`, the expression will evaluate to `$false` and the hashtable entrt will be skipped. Conversely, if no items match `snagit`, it will evaluate to `$true`

---

As [Ansgar just reminded me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969350/powershell-to-search-hash-table-values-with-notlike-or-notmatch/45969517?noredirect=1#comment78898469_45969517), the nested `Where-Object` statement isn't actually necessary when evaluating strings, since `-like` doubles as a filter operator on collections:

```
$results = $hash.GetEnumerator() |Where-Object {
    -not($_.Value -like '*snagit*')
}
```

Comment: Darn, beat me to it. You don't need the nested `Where-Object`, though, `-not ($_.Value -like '*snagit*')` should be sufficient.

Comment: To add some explanation, you cannot use `-notlike` or `-notmatch` here, because that would filter only matching elements from the values. Unless all array elements match the pattern you'll still end up with a non-empty array, which [evaluates to `$true`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators/). Instead you need to check if any element of the array matches, and then negate that condition to get "no element matches".

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thanks, completely forgot that we're working on bare strings here, I need some sleep ^_^

Comment: While both of these options worked, for some reason it looks like I received slightly different results. I end up sorting and then exporting to csv and they're different sizes. e.g. The nested where has more results

Comment: It turns out there were incorrect results within the nest where clause.